# Explanation of the Intel 1155 "Sandy-Bridge" chipsets

Tags: chipset, sandy-bridge

[Originally](http://rethinkthought.com/intel-sandy-bridges-h67-p67-and-z68-differences-explained/) there was an H67 (with graphics), a P67 (for overclocking), and a z68 (for both).

However, now it seems like there is a whole slew of alterations to this chipsets and I'm looking for an explanation of each one and it's purpose or audience.

- H61/H67/HM67
- P43/P45/P55/P67
- Q57/QM57/Q67
- Z68

Comment: All the non 6* chicpsets aren't "SB" chipsets.

Comment: What @bamboon said - those aren't Sandy Bridge at all.  For the record, 'M' just indicates a mobile (read: laptop) variant.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the [cougar point](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/37529/Cougar-Point) products page at ark.intel.com and [compare them](http://ark.intel.com/compare/52816,52801,52811,52810,52812,52809,52807,52806). Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155#Original_Sandy_Bridge_Chipsets).

As you'll see the differences concern [FDI support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_Display_Interface), CPU overclocking, USB and SATA ports number, PCI support, etc.